# Redirect URL to contain hashbang before processing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, hashbang

I need to provide an external API a callback URL however they do not support '#' in the URL. This does not work for us as we are using hashbang mode and not html5 mode.

We are using ui-router to navigate between pages and I would like to know how I can intercept the incoming URL (that does not contain a hashbang) and insert a hashbang before it gets processed so that the user can be navigated to the correct page.

For example: 
If a user encounters 'http://mySite/home'  then I want to be able to redirect them to 'http://mySite/#/home'.

-- Edit -- 
After exchange with @Gaiazov below it looks like I may need a server-side redirect (and not a rewrite) of this browser URL. How would I do this with Mvc?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a server side url rewrite like this. It will redirect all urls to your angular page with a query parameter containing the original url.

```
private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "/myapp.html?route=";

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(url)))
    {
        Context.RewritePath(ROOT_DOCUMENT + Context.Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
    }
}
```

Then, in your angular app

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
])

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('table', {
      url: '/{table:products|customers}'
    })
    .state('table.edit', {
      url: '/edit/:id'
    })
    .state('home', {
      url: '/*path',  // special 'catch all route',
      template: "Home"
  });

  var re = /^\?path=(.+)/i;

  $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
    // what this function returns will be set as the $location.url
    var path = window.location.search;
    var matches = path.match(re);
    if (matches) {
      console.log(matches);
      path = matches[1];
      return path; 
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home'); 
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.2.13" data-semver="0.2.13" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <a href="#/products/edit/5">/products/edit/5</a><br/>
    <a href="#/customers/edit/5">/customers/edit/5</a><br/>
    <a href="#/not-a-table/edit/5">/not-a-table/edit/5</a><br/>

    <a href="?path=/products/edit/5">?path=/products/edit/5</a>
    <div ui-view=""></div>

    <pre>
      <!-- Here's some values to keep an eye on in the sample in order to understand $state and $stateParams -->
      $state = {{$state.current.name}}
      $params = {{$state.params}}
      $stateParams = {{$stateParams}}
      $state full url = {{ $state.$current.url.source }}
    </pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `otherwise()` approach does not work in my case. It works well for all URL's that do contain hashbangs, but does not work for the specific case I need where the URL will not have a hashbang.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need URL rewriting on server side.

Comment: Okay, I am trying out `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` however it looks like this only deals with the virtual path and not the one that is entered on the browser (which contains the '#'). I need to be able to modify the path that is seen in the browser. Otherwise, this approach only partially works in that  I can see my page however it is disconnected from my javascript.

Comment: you can't rewrite to hash urls. your best bet is to rewrite to a url with original path in the query, and then in angular, to parse the query parameter.

I've updated the answer to show exactly how to do that.